# How would I use XStream to produce smaller output for simple maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, xstream

I serialize the data of my application with xstream. Since it should be read by other applications - or even viewed manuall I'd like to touch up the XML.

I have big maps of very simple types like `TreeMap<Integer,Double>` and `TreeMap<String,Double>`. I want to make my output more compact for these. Say from:

```
<entry>
    <int>56</int>
    <double>38.0</double>
</entry>
```

to `<entry key="56">38.0</entry>`

Unfortunately my experiments using `this.aliasAttribute(Entry.class, "key", "key")` fail with null pointer exception.

And I'm having problems to understand how I would write/register an `Converter` that would  handle `TreeMap<Integer,Double>` but keeps the default behaviour for `TreeMap<Object,MyComplexObject>` .

Maybe you can point me to a solution, thanks.

---

maybe the stacktrace can give some information.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:128)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldOrNull(FieldDictionary.java:113)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.field(FieldDictionary.java:92)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.getField(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:181)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AttributeMapper.addAttributeFor(AttributeMapper.java:169)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.useAttributeFor(XStream.java:1226)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.aliasAttribute(XStream.java:1192)
    at myproject.XstreamSerializer.<init>(XstreamSerializer.java:43)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should fix the null-pointer?

Comment: Suppose I should. But how? I suppose I shouldn't be using `Entry.class` - but I fail to see which is the appropriate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `TreeMapConverter` in `XStream`
May be it can help you out.
You can further read about this [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/TreeMapConverter.html)

Comment: hmm unfortunately it seems this is as close at I can get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This: http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/xml/CompactWriter.html and a CustomConverter can help you.